# Magento 2 : How to Import Custom Module's Less file in Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, theme, less, custom-theme

I am creating custom theme without parent. Now, I want to add custom less file inside Magento_Theme folder.

File path : **app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_mycustom.less**

I tried to call this file inside **app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/css/_sources.less** file. But, it's not working. I added this below line in **_sources.less** file

```
@import '../Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_mycustom.less';
```

How can I call it without **_module.less** file?

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in **app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/css/_sources.less**

```
//@magento_import 'source/_mycustom.less'; // Theme modules
```

If you need use custom less file, you should write less code from scratch.
for example:

If you create a new file listing.less in your theme then you should use only variables which use only in this file.

for example:

listing.less

```
@text-color: black;

.body {
  color: @text-color;
}
```

You can't use variables with magento lib in this file but if you want to use their then you need add this construction in your file:

```
@import '../../source/lib/_lib.less'; // Global lib
```

Comment: It seems like not working. Actually, I want to import source/lib/_lib.less file. I did like this //@magento_import 'source/lib/_lib.less'; But, It's not working.

Comment: When I deploy theme, It's return error @text__color is undefined in file from /var/www/html/m242/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/Magento_Catalog/css/listing.less file.

Comment: @AnkitaPatel I think issue with file listing.less. You should use _listing.less and import this file because magento will read this file and will try to compile less but if file start with underscore then magento ignore this file.

Comment: Actually, I created custom theme without parent. So, I want to call listing.less file only in listing page. Still, I need to use _listing.less name?

Comment: I added <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/listing.css" /> inside head tag in catalog_category_view.xml for right now.

Comment: Can you please guide me? M i going in right way or not?

Comment: If you create a new file listing.less in your theme then you should use only variables which use only in this file.

for example:

listing.less
`@text-color: black;`
`.body {`
`color: @text-color;`
`}`

Comment: You mean I need to do same as like this in all module's files? Is it not other way for that? same as like global variable for all files. @text-color.

Comment: Yes, because the file haven't access for variables which have location on ui lib magento. But I write in answer alternative solution.